# How to set Image Source to a picture from .dll or .winmd in windows phone 8.1?

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I am new to **windows phone 8.1** developping and focus on **library dev**.
In the wp 8.0 era,I know if I want to create a Image instance.
I just write

```
amapLogo.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Com.AMap.Api.Maps" + ";component/Resources/ap2.data", UriKind.Relative));
```

*need to point here is that "/Com.AMap.Api.Maps" is my library output dll*
**It works fine.**

If I **keep the same code** in wp8.1 developping
exception appears

```
An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The given System.Uri cannot be converted into a Windows.Foundation.Uri. Please see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849 for details.
```

I browse http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=215849
and find that two ways to set the ImageSource correctly.
the **ms-appx** or **ms-appx-web** scheme to create an absolute URI.
but it is used for getting a resource in the app package
*what I want is getting a resource from my dll*
so

- What can I do to create a Image instance using way of setting
  ImageSource.
- Or is there anther way to do what i want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just Solve it!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh965322.aspx

To access files stored inside the same package, but from a class library, use the class library name:

```
<Image Source="/ClassLibraryName/images/logo.png" />
```